# How to change html file to another html file on screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is when you change the screen size to scale of a phone ( width wise ) that you get a different html file or something like this.

Comment: you means with `media queries` for example ?

Comment: Google for "responsive web design"

Comment: No, you see, the page will have home,shop ect. but on the phone scale sized version i want to know how to change these attributes ( the home, shop ect. ) to something else, if possible. so you start of with 1,2,3,4 but with a new scale you get 5,6,7,8,

Comment: can you use jQuery library ?

Comment: Use media queries to have the elements you want displayed on XXX width, and then opposite for smaller width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As previously mentioned you should really use media queries and responsive dev to achieve the result you are looking for.**

If however there are specific pages you have identified that simply have to use a different page then you could use something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var doRelocation = function() {

    var currentWidth = window.innerWidth,
        breakpoint = 800,
        newLocation = 'new-page.html';

    if (currentWidth < breakpoint) {
        window.location.replace(newLocation);
    }

}

doRelocation();

window.addEventListener('resize', doRelocation);

</script>
```

This script is pretty basic but the function runs on load to determine the screen width and also on resize. It'll only work in modern browsers but I guess there aren't many small screened devices running IE8.